# Lenovo ThinkPad s440 network

Tags: networking, drivers, wifi

Does anybody know how to configure wifi on Lenovo ThinkPad s440 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS? I can't configure it even with LAN. But anyway, wifi is the first thing I need. I can't find any driver for linux. As I see it from ([official specs link](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201306-13872/)) Ubuntu uses `Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller` to establish network. Can anybody suggest a solution? A driver, a way to configure wifi or anything?..

lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 0a04 (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 0a16 (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 0a0c (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 9c31 (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 9c3a (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 9c20 (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9c10 (rev e4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9c12 (rev e4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9c14 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9c16 (rev e4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9c18 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 9c26 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9c43 (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device 9c03 (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 9c22 (rev 04)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 10)
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 08b2 (rev 73)
05:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5227 (rev 01)
06:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Device 6660
```

Comment: could you post the output of `lspci`?

Comment: Sure! Edited the post.

Comment: you need to load the iwlwifi kernel module for wifi, just add iwlwifi to /etc/modules . then run `modprobe iwlwifi`; you'll see your new device with `ifconfig -a`. Your wifi hardware is Intel 7260. In some cases you need also the firmware, if the module wont load. See also your `dmesg` output.

Comment: Your ethernet (lan) module seems to be `r8169`, try to follow like explained before.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really helpful info. I will try this out because LTS version is prefered over 3-months support.

Comment: That is *wired* network, not wireless

Comment: Hah, read it like weird. Nope, failed with Ubuntu13.10 - didn't recognize video card. Also can't install iwlwifi module into kernel. `ifconfig -a` shows only eth0 and lo.

Answer (score 1):

Tried install Ubuntu 13.10. It worked. Not the way I actually wanted to setup the wireless, but it worked. Solution found [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2191688)

Unfortunately, 13.10 didn't recognize my video card and couldn't load graphics. So, I finally found solution and reposted it [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/410317/lenovo-thinkpad-s440-network/410347#410347)

So, steps (by chili555) are: """ I suggest you download this to your desktop: http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v3.11-rc3/backports-3.11-rc3-1.tar.bz2 Right-click it and select 'Extract Here.' Now open a terminal and do:

```
cd Desktop/backports-3.11-rc3-1/
make defconfig-iwlwifi
make
sudo make install
```

Now download the required firmware here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/58267392/iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode.zip Please download it to your desktop. Right-click and select 'Extract Here.' Now open a terminal and do:

```
sudo cp Desktop/iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode /lib/firmware/
sudo modprobe -r iwldvm  <--If it is not loaded, OK, please proceed
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi <--If it is not loaded, OK, please proceed
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

Your wireless should now be working. """ Thanks!

Comment: So what are the steps you did?